# Restrict month and year in datepicker based on first field

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I have two month-year date picker field i want to restrict second month-year filed to select below the first month-year field value that is second month-year field shows only after the month-year of first month-year field please guide me how to achieve this my script is

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
     $('#month1_inp,#month2_inp').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
        changeYear: true, //this option for allowing user to select from year range
        dateFormat: "yy-mm",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        yearRange: '2014:+0'
     }).focus(function() {
        var thisCalendar = $(this);
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            of: $(this)
        }); 
        $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
        });
   });
});
```